Logback Set Interval and cronExpression programmatically
In my app. I need to create Logger dynamically. And I use logback and following code for logger creation:
 public void test() {
    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

    RollingFileAppender customAppender = new RollingFileAppender();
    customAppender.setContext(context);
    customAppender.setName("CUSTOM_APPENDER");
    customAppender.setFile("logs/custom_log.log");

    TimeBasedRollingPolicy rollingPolicy = new TimeBasedRollingPolicy();
    rollingPolicy.setContext(context);
    rollingPolicy.setFileNamePattern("logs/custom_log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm}.log");
    rollingPolicy.setParent(customAppender);
    rollingPolicy.start();

    SizeAndTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy policy = new SizeAndTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy();
    rollingPolicy.setTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy(policy);
    rollingPolicy.start();

    PatternLayoutEncoder encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
    encoder.setContext(context);
    encoder.setPattern("%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level - %msg%n");
    encoder.setCharset(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    encoder.start();

    customAppender.setRollingPolicy(rollingPolicy);
    customAppender.setEncoder(encoder);
    customAppender.start();

    Logger customLogger = context.getLogger("CUSTOM_LOGGER");
    customLogger.addAppender(customAppender);
    customLogger.setAdditive(false); 
    customLogger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
}

I need possibility to set interval and cronExpression to SizeAndTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy programatically. But such setters don't present.
For instance analogue in .xml configuration:
Interval
 <appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<file>logs/app.log</file>
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>logs/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
    <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <interval>2</interval>
        <modulate>true</modulate>
    </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
</rollingPolicy>

CronExpression
<appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<file>logs/app.log</file>
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>logs/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.CronTriggeringPolicy">
        <cronExpression>0 0 13 * * ?</cronExpression>
    </triggeringPolicy>
</rollingPolicy>

How can I implement such configurations programmatically ?
